# Error when using gulp, js-lint

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, jslint, ros

I downloaded the ros-control-center (https://github.com/pantor/ros-control-center) and I am trying to develop it for myself.
I already did npm install, but when i run gulp i get the following errors:

```
[09:12:35] Using gulpfile ~/proj/ros-control-centers/gulpfile.js
[09:12:35] Starting 'js-lint'...
[09:12:35] Starting 'watch'...
[09:12:35] Finished 'watch' after 12 ms
[09:12:35] 

/home/monero/proj/ros-control-centers/app/control/control.controller.js
  1:5  error  Parsing error: Unexpected token ros

/home/monero/proj/ros-control-centers/app/helper/domains.service.js
  1:1  error  Parsing error: The keyword 'class' is reserved

/home/monero/proj/ros-control-centers/app/helper/quaternions.service.js
  1:1  error  Parsing error: The keyword 'class' is reserved

/home/monero/proj/ros-control-centers/app/parameters/parameters.directive.js
  6:15  error  Parsing error: Unexpected token (

/home/monero/proj/ros-control-centers/app/navbar/navbar.directive.js
  5:15  error  Parsing error: Unexpected token (

/home/monero/proj/ros-control-centers/app/settings/settings.controller.js
  1:1  error  Parsing error: The keyword 'class' is reserved

/home/monero/proj/ros-control-centers/app/settings/settings.factory.js
  1:1  error  Parsing error: The keyword 'class' is reserved

    /home/monero/proj/ros-control-centers/app/services/service.directive.js
      6:15  error  Parsing error: Unexpected token (

    /home/monero/proj/ros-control-centers/app/topics/topic.directive.js
      6:15  error  Parsing error: Unexpected token (

✖ 9 problems (9 errors, 0 warnings)

[09:12:35] 'js-lint' errored after 119 ms
[09:12:35] ESLintError in plugin 'gulp-eslint'
Message:
    Failed with 9 errors
```

This seems like a pretty basic problem, but I couldn't find any solution online to fix this problem. If anyone needs further information just let me know, and thanks in advance!

Comment: I clond the above repo and installed all the packages required and executed `gulp`. I was getting around `24 warnings` and `0 errors`. Check that you installed all required packages.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answer!
If I run npm install, as far as I can see all required packages are installed... I checked the packages with npm ls
I get 3 warnings:

```
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@2.0.10: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue

npm WARN deprecated minimatch@0.2.14: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue

npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@1.2.3: graceful-fs v3.0.0 and before will fail on node releases >= v7.0. Please update to graceful-fs@^4.0.0 as soon as possible. Use 'npm ls graceful-fs' to find it in the tree.
```

gulp is installed globally, I only did npm install. Is there something obvious I forgot? I am pretty new in developing.